# How to send ping using Eclipse Paho MQTT client?

Tags: android, mqtt

We've just started building our own push notification system (due to client's requirement) for Android and found Eclipse Paho (http://www.eclipse.org/paho/). Needless to say, this project is really exciting.

The problem with Android is, if the CPU is in sleep state, the MQTT client may not get the chance to send ping at its set interval. The workaround is using AlarmManager to wake it up and get the job done. The Android documentation says:

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.
>   Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock.
>   This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your
>   onReceive() method completes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

I need to be sure that I could send the ping command within that onReceive() method while the CPU has PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, so I was searching a way to manually sending ping to server but it seems the client doesn't expose any such method. Am I missing something? Or, what is the workaround here except publishing my own "ping message"? I want to avoid that because of:

1. Larger overhead
2. We'll ensure that Android clients are subscriber only, may be with Mosquitto's ACL. They will not be allowed to publish messages.

Comment: While doing this, have you noticed that the MqttService stops if you swipe away the app from recent apps? After that, no messages are received and you are disconnected from the broker. How (if you have) did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been doing some work with MQTT on Android and I've experienced exactly the same issue.

As Dale says, the old version of the MQTT client used to have an explicit ping() method, but unfortunately this is now hidden away.

The simplest approach, and the one I use, is to explicitly publish a 1 byte message to a particular topic, to serve as the keepalive. I don't think this should add much to the overhead of your application and, while I'm not familiar with Mosquitto's ACL, I assume you could have every client use the same 'keepalive' topic and just provide write access to all. This shouldn't affect security as long as no-one can read from the topic.

An alternative approach would be to have the server send the client(s) a 'keepalive' message at QoS 1 or 2 (pub/sub through a single topic to all for efficiency) as, due to the QoS flows, this will involve the client sending a message back to the server under the covers; which will serve as the keepalive. This has the advantage of keeping your clients as subscriber only; however it's incompatible with 'clean session = false' (as you would have large amounts of messages queued up for delivery to clients who are offline for a while - needlessly affecting performance on reconnect).

Unfortunately these are the only two workarounds that I can currently think of.

---

Also, as a brief aside, I've experienced a number of issues using the MqttDefaultFilePersistence on Android, so you might want to be aware of this. In particular to do with file locking and problems when re-instantiating the client. To get around this I've created an implementation of MqttClientPersistence built on top of an SQLite database and this is much more robust; you might want to do the same.

Comment: Thank you! The reason of not allowing the clients to publish is I saw the [max length](https://answers.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+question/188424) of messages supported by MQTT/Mosquitto is too high, according to the link ~260MB. Do you think this puts a threat on the server? As the free brokers (Mosquitto/RSMB) doesn't support SSL, plain username/password based authentication didn't seem secure enough to me, so I wanted to forbid publish access to anybody but the server itself, where Man-in-the-middle attack is not possible. I'm not security expert, this is just assumption.

Comment: One more thing on the side note: Eclipse Paho has an internal memory persistence class `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.MemoryPersistence` , I'm using that to avoid the hassles you mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, tough one. I guess it depends how robust the broker is and whether it can handle someone bombarding it with ~260MB messages in an attempt to swamp it; as this is the only attack I think this would leave you open to. As you say, plain username/password isn't going to provide any protection since it could just be sniffed on the wire.

Comment: Is the second approach, using QoS 1 or 2 messages sent from the server, feasible? Or do you need clean session = true?

Comment: Yes, that seems the best option til now, as I don't need the server to remember sessions on reconnect. Thank you for your time!

Comment: stephendnicholas, would a 0-byte message (empty byte array) work as well as a 1-byte message?

Comment: Navigateur : Yes, good point. 0-byte should work just as well, and save you some data :)

Comment: Please note that the statement above "the free brokers (Mosquitto/RSMB) doesn't support SSL" is outdated. Mosquitto supports SSL since [version 1.0](http://mosquitto.org/2012/08/version-1-0-released/) released 08/2012.

Comment: @stephendnicholas may i know how you made persistence file on top of sqlite?

Comment: @david Unfortunately my implementation is proprietary code, so I cannot share it. However it was a relatively simple implementation of the MqttClientPersistence interface that interacts with an sqlite db to perform the required 'get' and 'put' calls (reading from / writing to the db).

Comment: @stephendnicholas i really need this, If possible can i email you? and maybe its simple for you but not really for me as of now. beacuse in default file persistence i see .bup, .lck and .msg i think, so I dont reallly get it how you do crud there.

Answer (score 10):

I came across this issue when writing MQTT apps for Android a year or so ago. I've written about it at some length at http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 but in short, yes - I saw the same problem that you describe where if the CPU is asleep when the MQTT client should send it's ping, then the ping never gets sent.

The difference is that I was using a different MQTT client library to you (this was before the days of Paho), and the client library that I used did have a ping() method that I could call. (The full source for my implementation is at that link, and it does solve this problem).

Can you not extend the implementation of the Paho client library to include the PING command? I assume it should be a reasonably small modification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I saw your post before before starting working on it, it is a great resource on the topic, I must admit. I thought about "extending" Paho client library, but it seems it is not possible (in a good manner). It stores ClientComms class instance inside a private field and that ClientComms object stores ClientState object inside it, also in a private field. ClientState is responsible for managing pings (request, response and time). I'll have to modify the core in that case, making it a mess :(

Answer (score 3):

my solution:

(1) modify: `ClientComms comms;` from `protected` to `public` (in package `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3`)

```
public class MqttAsyncClient implements IMqttAsyncClient { // DestinationProvider {
    //...
    public ClientComms comms;  // Add by Ben for pingreq*
    //...
}
```

(2)  define new class: (derived from `MqttClient`)

```
public class MqttClient2 extends MqttClient {

    public MqttClient2(String serverURI, String clientId,   MqttClientPersistence persistence) throws MqttException {
        super(serverURI, clientId, persistence);
    }

    public void pingreq()  throws MqttException {

        MqttDeliveryToken token = new MqttDeliveryToken(getClientId());
        MqttPingReq pingMsg = new MqttPingReq();
        aClient.comms.sendNoWait(pingMsg, token);

    }
}
```

(3) anywhere, you can:

```
MqttClient2 mClient = new MqttClient2(url, mDeviceId, mDataStore);
mClient.pingreq();
```

hope this can be helpfull for you.

Comment: to avoid modifying class `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient` (step 1) you can create class MqttClient2 in a package named `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3` (procced to step 2 instantly)

Comment: This works only till mqtt-client-0.4.0. In mqtt-client-0.4.1-SNAPSHOT field aClient of class MqttClient has been change to private from protected thus not accessible in the child class. Is there any other solution to make it work for o.4.1-SNAPSHOT and later?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to modify the paho code and make a ping at any time. If we use publishing topic to keep alive, we have to send at least 7 or 8 bytes to server. Yes, 8 bytes is still not big data. But the heartbeat of MQTT is only 2bytes. We have lost the best advantage of MQTT.

Look deeply into the paho code, I modify it and write a public method named nnnn() in MQTTClient. This method could send MqttPingReq to th server. the implemetation can be found here...https://github.com/chinesejie/paho-for-android