# Android MQTT unable to create client

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying to create an mqtt client in my android service using the paho client library . 
The mosquitto broker is running  on my local machine. 
I am getting an MqttPersistenceException exception when i try to create a new instance of the MQTTClient.

//create client
port=1883
mqttConnSpec="tcp://"+ipaddressOflocalMachine+":"+ port 
mqttClient =  new MqttClient(mqttConnSpec, mqttClientId)

the exception does not give any reason.
I am successfully able to communicate using a java console app.
Is there something extra needed when running this in the android emulator.
Any help is much appreciated

thanks
Ben

Comment: You might get a better chance of a useful response if you ask on the Paho mailing list: https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/paho-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share a little more of your code - are you setting up an persistence class?

There are a number of good resources which discuss Java/Paho MQTT clients on Android. The basic thing is that you do need to implement a persistence class or specify the in-memory or file one provided. This was discussed in [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065624/how-to-send-ping-using-ecipse-paho-mqtt-client). Also see [this "bug"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384083) which explains that you need to ensure that user.dir is set or use a different persistence method. There is a [list of additional resources on the MQTT wiki](http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform).