# again: Android MQTT unable to create client

Tags: android, adt, mqtt

I'm trying to create an MqttClient in Android, using an Android emulator (Nexus7) on ADT (Eclipse 3.8.0 on a Linux Fedora17.
I found this question answered [(Android MQTT unable to create client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407045/android-mqtt-unable-to-create-client), but it failed to solve my problem.

I created an activity that allows the user to enter the directory where to store the presistence file, but there is no way to avoid catching the exception.
I tried with "/mnt/sdcard/", "/mnt/", "/mnt/sdcard/tmp/" and similar.

Do I need to pay attention to particular settings in Android emulator on in Eclipse project?
Are there any uses-permissions to be included in the application?

I looked at the various mqtt resources mentioned in the quoted answered question, but I couldn't manage to find an answer.

This is my code:

```
package com.storassa.android.mqttsample;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MqttSample extends Activity {

    Button okButton = null;
    AutoCompleteTextView inputTextView = null;
    TextView errorTextView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mqtt_sample);

        okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        inputTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.InputText);
        errorTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorText);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    String dir = inputTextView.getText().toString();
                    MqttDefaultFilePersistence mdfp = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(
                            dir);
                    MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://127.0.0.1:1833",
                            "0001", mdfp);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    String errorText = "";
                    for (StackTraceElement error : e.getStackTrace())
                        errorText += error.toString() + "\n";
                    errorTextView.setText(errorText);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mqtt_sample, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is the Stack:

```
MqttException(0) at
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.open(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:74)
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:183)
com.storassa.android.mqttsample.MqttSample$1.onClick(MqttSample.java:38)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I just tested the same app on a real smartphone (Samsung Mini 2) with the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a whole day spent in understanding the issue and in googling anywhere to find it, eventually I got it: very simply a permission has to be added to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I don't know whether internal directories can be used instead of the sdcard.

As this is the first time I answer my own question, let me know whether it is a good etiquette to flag as correct answer my own answer (I found different opinions on this topics)

Answer (score 10):

You could alternatively use an instance of the class MemoryPersistence if you don't rely on file persistency.

So the call to get a client would be:

```
MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(host, clientId, persistence);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the possibility of using internal memory, but I'm just approaching MQTT and I'd like to know where the issue was about file persistence.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

There is a bit mocking around the WAMP as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
        MqttClientPersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir);
        mqttclient = new MqttAsyncClient(url.toString(), clientId, persistence);
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely useful. Please consider adding some context to your answer.

Comment: As Chris said, you really need to explain what you mean. Even more so if answering an older question that has an accepted answer you should explain why your answer is better.

Comment: What explanation do you need? He created internal persistence variable and passed it to the method, that's it. I applied it, no more persistence permission error, thanks! 

For the unsatisfied, ungrateful and toxic commenters who probably didn't even have this issue but regardless came here to downvote and complain - shame on you. Next time try his solution before crying, don't expect everyone to spoon feed you and especially for free.

Comment: I agree to @zemaitis. Everything is self-explaining and works like a charm for me. This amount of downvotes for no reason is absolutely not needed, he just helped the person asking. +1 for you dude, thank you!

Comment: Reviewers need to understand that stackoverflow is not our fulltime work and we share when we have time. If we don't have time we at least point you to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the MQTT client code is trying to open a file on the local storage to store messages in when publishing at high (1/2) QOS levels. There will be 2 causes for the error:

1.You may not have granted storage access to the application

2.You are unlikely to have permission to write to the default location that the MQTT client chooses.

The easiest way to get round this is to use the in memory storage (org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence) for the MQTT client.

```
...
MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
client = new MqttClient("tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883", clientId);
...
```

Once you get round that problem you are likely to run into the issue of doing network io on the UI thread. To avoid that I suggest you look at the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) code that Android provides

Comment: The default location the class MqttDefaultFilePersistence uses is System.getProperty("user.dir"). On my OpenShift instance this returned the root directory "/" which really confused me because there's no way to write to the root directory in Linux environments I think so the open file command fails anyway.